# batch: for command to read a list of elements

Tags: batch-file

I've a simple task for a simple subroutine but i can understand for command syntax with quotes and dobble quotes.

In a batch file:

```
call :mysubroutine "text1;text2;text with spaces;text4" "option1A|option2A;option2B||option with spaces4A;optionwitoutspaces4B"
```

I want print something like:

```
1: text1   option1A 
2: text2   option2A;option2B 
3: text with spaces  
4: text4   option with spaces4A;optionwithoutspaces4B
```

can you help me?

Comment: There are literally dozens of previous posts here that demonstrate how to use the for command and handle quotes and parse text. Have you made *any* effort at all to do this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :mysubroutine "text1;text2;text with spaces;text4" "option1A|

option2A;option2B||option with spaces4A;optionwitoutspaces4B"
goto :EOF

:mysubroutine
set "first=%~1"
set "second=%~2"
set i=0
for %%a in ("%first:;=" "%") do (
   set /A i+=1, j=0
   for %%b in ("%second:|=" "%") do (
      set /A j+=1
      if !i! equ !j! echo !i!. %%~a   %%~b
   )
)
```